# .N not working properly within data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I came across a surprising result with `data.table`. Here is a really simple example :

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(x = 1:10)
df[,x[x>3][.N]]
[1] NA
```

This syntax gives `NA`, but this work:

```
df[,x[x>3][1]]
[1] 4
```

and of course this

```
df[,x[.N]]
[1] 10
```

I know that in this simple example case you can do

```
df[x>3,x[.N]]
```

but I wanted to use the `df[,x[x>3][.N]]` syntax while using lapply on `.SD` to avoid a loop on the `i` selection, so something like

```
df2 <- data.table(x = rep(1:10,2), y = rep(2:11,2),ID = rep(c("A","B"),each = 10))
cols = c("x","y")
df2[,lapply(.SD,function(x){x[x>3][.N]}),.SDcols = cols, by = ID]
```

But this fail, same as in my simple example. Is it because `.N` is not implemented in this case, or am I doing something wrong ?

My actual work around:

```
Reduce(merge,lapply(cols,function(col){df2[col>3,setNames(list( get(col)[.N]),col),by = ID]}))

   ID  x  y
1:  A 10 11
2:  B 10 11
```

but I am not fully happy with it, I find it less readable. Has anyone an explanation and a better work around ?
Thank you !!

Comment: @dww Thanks, it makes sense. But how can I do something similar then? `df[,x[x>3][sum(x>3)]]` ?

Comment: @dww Perfect! thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df[,x[x>3]]` has 7 elements. `.N` is 10. You are trying to subset a vector out of range.

So you can access the last element of the vector in `lapply` using:

```
df2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) tail(x[x>3], 1) ), .SDcols = c('x','y'), by = ID]
```

Or more idiomatic for data.table we can use

```
df2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) last(x[x>3]) ), .SDcols = c('x','y'), by = ID]
```